# Client is not receiving data in C# client-server application

Tags: c#

I have a C# client-server application. And I tried to learn the async sockets, but I struggle at understanding how they work. (I am new to this). My client is blocking and not receiving the answers from the server, even though it gets the same number of bytes, the message is always null or empty. I started from the Microsoft example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example and the one for the server. I searched through a lot of question but I can not understand, please help. This is my code:

```
//THIS IS THE CLIENT
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;
using core;
using System.IO;

namespace client
{
    public class AsynchronousClient
    {
        // The port number for the remote device.  
        private const int port = 9000;

        // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.  
        public static ManualResetEvent connectDone =
            new ManualResetEvent(false);
        public static ManualResetEvent sendDone =
            new ManualResetEvent(false);
        public static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =
            new ManualResetEvent(false);

        // The response from the remote device.  
        public Message response = new Message();

        private Socket client;

        private IPHostEntry ipHostInfo;
        private IPAddress ipAddress;
        private IPEndPoint remoteEP;

        public AsynchronousClient()
        {
            // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.  
            // The name of the
            // remote device is "localhost".  
            ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
            ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
            client = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
                    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect to the remote endpoint.  
            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();

        }
        public void StartClient()
        {
            // Connect to a remote device.  
            try
            {

                // Send test data to the remote device.  
                Send(new Message { Content = "This is a test<EOF>" });
                sendDone.WaitOne();

                // Receive the response from the remote device.  
                Receive();
                receiveDone.WaitOne();

                // Write the response to the console.  
                Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response.Content);

                // Release the socket.  
                client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                client.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                // Complete the connection.  
                client.EndConnect(ar);

                Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                    client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

                // Signal that the connection has been made.  
                connectDone.Set();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void Receive()
        {
            try
            {
                // Create the state object.  
                StateObject state = new StateObject();
                state.workSocket = client;

                // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.  
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

        }

        private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the state object and the client socket
                // from the asynchronous state object.  
                StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
                Socket client = state.workSocket;

                // Read data from the remote device.  
                int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

                Message receivedMessage = new Message();

                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.  

                    receivedMessage = (Message)Serializer.FromStream(new MemoryStream(state.buffer));
                    // Get the rest of the data.  
                    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                        new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                }
                else
                {
                    // All the data has arrived; put it in response.  

                    response = receivedMessage;

                    // Signal that all bytes have been received.  
                    receiveDone.Set();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void Send(Message message)
        {
            // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
            MemoryStream stream = Serializer.ToStream(message);
            byte[] byteData = stream.GetBuffer();

            // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
            client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
        }

        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
                int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
                Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);

                // Signal that all bytes have been sent.  
                sendDone.Set();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
THIS IS THE SERVER
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using core;
using server;


public class AsynchronousSocketListener
{
    // Thread signal.  
    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    IPHostEntry ipHostInfo;
    IPAddress ipAddress;
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint;

    Socket listener;

    public AsynchronousSocketListener()
    {
        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.  
        // The DNS name of the computer  
        // running the listener is "localhost".  
        ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
        ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 9000);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
        listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
             SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    }

    public void StartListening()
    {
        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.  
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (true)
            {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.  
                allDone.Reset();

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.  
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                listener.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener);

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.  
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();

    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.  
        allDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.  
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        // Create the state object.  
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        String content = String.Empty;

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket  
        // from the asynchronous state object.  
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the client socket.
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
        var buffer = new byte[2048];
        Message receivedMessage = new Message();
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
            //state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString( state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            receivedMessage = (Message)Serializer.FromStream(new MemoryStream(state.buffer));
            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read
            // more data.  
            content = receivedMessage.Content;
            if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
            {
                // All the data has been read from the
                // client. Display it on the console.  
                Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",
                    content.Length, content);
                //HandleMessage.handle(handler, receivedMessage);
                // Echo the data back to the client.

                Send(handler, receivedMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                // Not all data received. Get more.  
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket handler, Message message)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        MemoryStream stream = Serializer.ToStream(message);
        byte[] byteData = stream.GetBuffer();
        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }


}
```

The Message class only has 2 fields now, a String and User which is a class.. StateObject it would be the one from class. 
Also in Handle Message I am doing this : (because it is also connected to a database and here I would make the operations)

```
 public static class HandleMessage
    {
        private static BaseHandler baseHandler;

        public static void handle(Socket handler, Message message)
        {
            baseHandler = new BaseHandler();
            String[] received = message.Content.Split(' ');
            if(received[0].CompareTo("find") == 0)
            {
                if(received[1].CompareTo("user") == 0)
                {
                    var result = baseHandler.filterByUsername(received[2]);

                    Message sentMessage = new Message { userContent = result };
                    MemoryStream stream = Serializer.ToStream(sentMessage);
                    var bytesSent = handler.Send(stream.GetBuffer());
                }
            }
        }
```

And This is how I send a message to server:

```
 public User findByUsername(String username)
        {
            StringBuilder Content = new StringBuilder();
            Content.Append("find user ");
            Content.Append(username);
            Content.Append(" <EOF>");

            Message message = new Message { Content = Content.ToString() };
            asynchronousClient.Send(message);


            asynchronousClient.Receive();
            var result = asynchronousClient.response;
            return result.userContent;
        }
```

My client's response is only null and he is only receiving once. I am new to this, sorry for the long post.

Comment: There is no guarantee with TCP the entire message will be received in on chunk.  Max chunk size ~1500 bytes and during routing chunks can be split and recombined.  So you have to wait until you get the entire message before processing.  So the receiver has to wait until the end of message which can either be a character not part of the message or add a byte count to beginning of message and then wait until all the bytes are received before processing.  TCP also has a keep-alive message which is a message with zero bytes.  So zero bytes should not be used to close a connection.

Comment: I did tried to put sendDone.waitOne() and the same for receive, but now from the client I send the message " find user .. <EOF>" and in client it says sending 256 bytes. However, in server, I get this message, but it s saying that received 27 bytes and then everything freezes..

Comment: You need to append each chunk to a single message until you find EOF.   So in the State object there is a string builder.  Each message you append to the string builder until you get the EOF and then process.  I usually just use a string instead of a string builder.  Then remember before sending clear the string in the state object.

Comment: What if I would have more complicated types than a string, for example a class User and I need to send a user?

Comment: You have to define a message.  Messages can either be terminated with a character not in the message, preceded by a byte count, or be fixed length.